# Gradient not filling IBDesignable UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cagradientlayer, ibdesignable

I'm attempting to add a gradient on an @IBDesignable UIView. All was well in Simulator, but when I run it on a physical device, the gradient doesn't fill the screen. I've got my gradient code in a UIView extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func gradientFrom(_ colors: [UIColor]) {
        let cgColors = colors.map({return $0.cgColor})
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.locations =  [0.0, 1.0]
        gradient.colors = cgColors
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Next, my gradient-centric code from my UIView:

```
@IBDesignable class MyCustomView: UIView {

    var view = UIView()

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    fileprivate var gradientColors: [UIColor] = []

    @IBInspectable var gradientColor0: UIColor = UIColor.flatWhite {
        didSet {
            gradientColors.remove(at: 0)
            gradientColors.insert(gradientColor0, at: 0)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var gradientColor1: UIColor = UIColor.flatWhiteDark {
        didSet {
            gradientColors.remove(at: 1)
            gradientColors.insert(gradientColor1, at: 1)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
        setup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
        [gradientColor0, gradientColor1].forEach({gradientColors.append($0)})
        view.gradientFrom(gradientColors)
        label.textColor = labelFontColor
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textView.textColor = textViewFontColor
    }

    // MARK: - Nib handlers

    fileprivate func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    fileprivate func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "AttributionView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        return view
    }

    public func applyBackgroundGradient() {        
        view.gradientFrom(gradientColors)
    }

    func resizeView() {
        textView.sizeToFit()
        textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
    }
}
```

On MyViewController, I add a UIView, set its subclass to MyCustomView. Interface builder populates, but when I go to run it on a physical device, the gradient in MyCustomView does not fill the entire screen.

I tried running `applyBackgroundGradient` from `MyViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidAppear`, none of those seem to get the job done.

Any suggestions re: how to fix this are greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you set constraints on MyCustomView so that it will fill the screen?

Comment: Yes. I got the desired results in Simulator. I'm encountering this issue on a physical device.

Comment: You get the desired results on the simulator for all device sizes?

Comment: when do you call `applyBackgroundGradient` ? it should work inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews `, do you call it once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace

```
gradient.frame = self.bounds
```

with

```
gradient.frame.size = self.frame.size
gradient.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
```

and you definitely should call it like

```
var didLayoutSubviews = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if !self.didLayoutSubviews {
         self.didLayoutSubviews = true
         //apply gradient
         //you can also try to execute drawing inside `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`
    }
}
```

**Addendum from OP:**

Part of my problem derived from my `didSet` calls on the colors for the gradient. Instead of mucking around setting up the array in didSet, I moved the code for populating the `gradientColors` array down to the `applyBackgroundGradient` method.

```
@IBInspectable var gradientColor0: UIColor = UIColor.flatWhite {
    didSet {
        applyBackgroundGradient()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var gradientColor1: UIColor = UIColor.flatWhiteDark {
    didSet {
        applyBackgroundGradient()
    }
}
```

...and the gradient code on `MyCustomView` looks like this:

```
public func applyBackgroundGradient() {
    gradientColors = [gradientColor0, gradientColor1] 
    self.view.gradientFrom(gradientColors)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Part of my problem was the the frame. The other part was the way I was applying the gradient. I was doing too much work in the didSets of the gradient colors. Instead, I moved the array population code down to `applyBackgroundGradient()`. I'll add to the bottom of your answer.

Comment: @Adrian, `gradientColors = [gradientColor0, gradientColor1]` should suffice.

Comment: Adding the gradient in viewDidLayoutSubviews was the fix for me! Thanks!